# Google Maps reverse geocoding returns shorter name

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using reverse geocoding in Google Maps to get an address from a LatLng position.

However, the formatted address (formatted_address) returned in the result is shorter than the address that I get from using an autocomplete for the same point.

How can I get the same (longer) description using reverse geocoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar problem/request posted at: [Google Maps Address Components Geocoding vs Places API - Short vs Long Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055452/google-maps-address-components-geocoding-vs-places-api-short-vs-long-name)

For now, if you take the resulting formatted_address from the geocoder and pass it into a query for the new [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), get the details for the resulting place.reference, and lastly grab the formatted_address from that response, you'll get a long form address.

Not very clean (hence my [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4215&q=apitype%3AGeocoder%20type%3AEnhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) at gmaps-api issue list), but it should work for now.

Alex

Comment: I have been out of this so long, but I'm going to take your word for it. Thanks for the answer.