# Google Maps Address Components Geocoding vs Places API - Short vs Long Name

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

Hey there GMaps API developers. To start - what an incredible product and service the Google Maps/JS API v3 is - thank you so much! Now, with that important bit of sincere gratitude out of the way...

The `short_name` vs `long_name` options for address components is a nice feature, but for each service these two attributes mostly contain the same values, except geocode has what I would expect for `short_name` for both and places has what I would expect for `long_name` for both! *tears*

Before Places library came out I just assumed that Google didn't actually have short/long versions for street name, localities, etc - but now it seems you **do** have that formatting somewhere - maybe different product teams have different databases?

So what's the deal?

Image of what I'm talking about (would embed but this is my first stackoverflow question so no reputation): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lJCg.png

Detailed list of how I **wish** this worked:

- for routes, geocode's `short_name` places' `long_name`
- have the same "types" value for locality/sublocality between geocode and places (either is fine, just pick one)
- consistently provide short/long for state (administrative_area_level_1) - geocode gets this right but places doesn't
- same for country - and where is geocode getting its "USA" in the formatted address?
- would be neat if `postal_code` `long_name` had zip+4, but I would imagine that'd be a huge endeavor from a data standpoint

Thanks so much - looking forward to any insight on this behavior!

Code behind the image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>GMaps API V3 Geocoder vs Places Address Components | Short vs Long Name</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #map {height: 100px; width: 600px; border: 1px solid #333; margin-top: 0.6em; }
    table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
    table td {border-top: 1px solid #DDD; padding:4px 8px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map, geocoder, places, geocode_components, geocode_formatted, places_components, places_formatted
    function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({'address': '3 South Main Street, York New Salem, PA'},
      function (results, status) {
        geocode_components = results[0].address_components;
        geocode_formatted = results[0].formatted_address;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: results[0].geometry.location,
          zoom: 10
        });

        places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        places.search({location: results[0].geometry.location, radius:100, keyword: "Pizza"},
          function(results, status) {
            //get details - this feels a little extraneous to me, but y'all know best
            places.getDetails({reference: results[0].reference},
            function(result, status) {
              places_components = result.address_components;
              places_formatted = result.formatted_address;
              writeResults();
            });
          });
      });
    }

    function writeResults() {
    tbody = document.getElementById('results');
    formatted = document.getElementById('formatted');
    var rows = "";
    for(var i=0; i<geocode_components.length; i++) {
      var c = geocode_components[i];
      rows = rows + '<tr><td>Geocoding</td><td>' + c.types[0] + '</td><td>' + c.short_name + '</td><td>' + c.long_name + '</td></tr>';
    }

    for(var i=0; i<places_components.length; i++) {
      var c = places_components[i];
      rows = rows + '<tr><td>Places</td><td>' + c.types[0] + '</td><td>' + c.short_name + '</td><td>' + c.long_name + '</td></tr>';
    }
    tbody.innerHTML = rows;
    formatted.innerHTML = '<br />Geocode Formatted: ' + geocode_formatted + '<br />' + 'Places Formatted: ' + places_formatted;
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <table>
    <thead><tr><th>Service</th><th>Type</th><th>Short Name</th><th>Long Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody id="results"></tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="formatted"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you've placed your enhancement request in the wrong place. No big deal, just trying to help, but the better place for this is the [Google Maps Issue List](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/). Stack Overflow is intended for specific programming questions - things like: I've tried this and that, but neither work; can someone who has done this give me a little help? Your request certainly makes sense, I just think you've posted it to the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Sean - I will post it over there too - and thanks dda for the formatting help.

Comment: This feature request was solved in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821543

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments - this question (request) was fixed/implemented back in January, 2013, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821543